# Classifying spaces of odd dimensional $p$-spheres

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

By a statement on page 68 of Kane's book "The homology of Hopf spaces"(1988), I know that the classifying space $BS^{2n-1}_{(p)}$ of a $p$-local $(2n-1)$-dimensional sphere exists if $n$ divides $p-1$, where $p$ is a prime. It seems that the author didn't give the reference and I don't know why. Is it a sufficient and necessary condition? A reference to the statement is also very desirable.

Comment: I believe this is from Sullivan's *Geometric Topology: Localization, Periodicity, and Galois Symmetry*. See $\S4$ *Principal Spherical Fibrations*.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks!